# jaspersoft reporting error user lacks privilege or object not found

Tags: spring, jasper-reports, spring-jdbc

My first attempt at JasperSoft Reports, community edition.Installed the necessary plugin to get it to work in Spring Tool Suite. Created a new report project and added the data adapter to connect to a sql database and the connection worked fine. Then tried to create a new report and select a datasource and design a query. This is where the error is produced:

```
user lacks privilege or object not found:
```

and the object in this case happens to be the DB table. I have been unable to retrieve any solution online and hoping someone can direct me here.
Appreciate your response.